# Crystal Reports failed to open the connection

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports-xi

I am developing a desktop software which is creating proposals and invoices. I am storing my database (MySql) in a remote server. Everything is working perfectly fine in my PC which i am using for coding.

On client machine I can add,update and delete records without any problem. But when i try to open a record in then I am facing with an error below.

I was created the report in VB.NET but when I face with the error than I opened the rpt file in Crystal Reports XI Release 2 and updated data source location, verified database and save the file. Some part of my code is :

```
ElseIf Me.Text = "Tekliflere Gözat" Then
            Form16.Text = "Teklif Detayları:"

            Dim strReportPath As String
            Dim rptDoc As CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument
            strReportPath = My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "\Teklif.rpt"
            rptDoc = New ReportDocument
            rptDoc.Load(strReportPath)
            rptDoc.SetDatabaseLogon("USER_NAME", "PASSWORD", "SERVER_IP", "DB_NAME")
            Form16.CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rptDoc


            Form16.CrystalReportViewer1.SelectionFormula = "{teklif1.teklifno} =" & ListView1.SelectedItems(0).Text
            Form16.CrystalReportViewer1.Refresh()
            Form16.CrystalReportViewer1.RefreshReport()
            Form16.Show()
            Me.Close()
```

[image: Crystal reports Failed to open the connection]
Could you please advise. 
Thank you.
Regards
Oguz

Comment: Lookup how to apply TableLogonInfo. And, if it is at all possible, dump crystal Reports. This is just the first of many problems you will have.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found the solution. But first have to look at the casue. While connecting to a remote database via my software everthing is working fine. But when I was designing a report in CR, I created a connection in database expert menu. So that means locally I am describing to CR that where and how to connect. But when I install my software with all necessery components to the client machine CR report files searching the connection criteria and as a matter of course it can not find it in client machine.

So the solution is to install Mysql ODBC Connector to the client machine and configure it with the same settings in my PC. Or as an alternative solution, define all connection and database settings programatically in your code.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm having a similar problem, you said something about defining the connection and database settings programmatically, how can I do that for crystal reports? I set up the odbc connector on the client's pc but I'm not getting any data there

Comment: Hello amateur programmer.  If you can reach to your client pc you can follow the instructions I've mentioned [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/44153404) link. Or you can find the codes in Stoc OverFlow topics with a few search.  Regards  Oguz

Comment: I have followed your instructions but the problem is still there ! The thing is this problem is only with one pc, with the rest it's working fine