# failed to load connection crystalreport13 from IIS

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports, iis-7, iis-7.5, crystal-reports-xi

i tried to load crystal report on windows server 2012 R2 from IIS i get the error 
**Failed to open the connection. MA723DT 2608_14160_{B2777DB7-D4BD-4E31-8748-7E70DE55C132}.rpt** 
but its working in same machine from visual studio when debug the application

```
private void GetReport(string EmpID, string StartDate, string EndDate, string Conn, string Cmpid)
  {
      try {
          TableLogOnInfos TableLogOnInfos = new TableLogOnInfos();
          TableLogOnInfo TableLogOnInfo = new TableLogOnInfo();
          ConnectionInfo ConnectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo();
          SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
          Tables Tables;
          ReportDocument report = new ReportDocument();
          string FileName = "~/MA723BA.rpt";
          report.Load(Server.MapPath(FileName));
          if (Conn != "")
          {
              string ConnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[Conn].ConnectionString;
              if (ConnString.ToLower().StartsWith("metadata="))
              {
                  System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnectionStringBuilder efBuilder = new System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnectionStringBuilder(ConnString);
                  ConnString = efBuilder.ProviderConnectionString;
                  builder.ConnectionString = ConnString;

                  ConnectionInfo.ServerName = builder.DataSource;
                  ConnectionInfo.DatabaseName = builder.InitialCatalog;
                  ConnectionInfo.UserID = builder.UserID;
                  ConnectionInfo.Password = builder.Password;
                  Tables = report.Database.Tables;

                  foreach (CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table table in Tables)
                  {
                      TableLogOnInfo = table.LogOnInfo;
                      TableLogOnInfo.ConnectionInfo = ConnectionInfo;
                      table.ApplyLogOnInfo(TableLogOnInfo);
                  }

              }
          }
          ParameterRangeValue myParameterRangeValue = new ParameterRangeValue();

          myParameterRangeValue.StartValue = StartDate;
          myParameterRangeValue.EndValue = EndDate;
          report.SetParameterValue(0, EmpID);

          report.SetParameterValue(1, myParameterRangeValue);
          CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = report;
          CrystalReportViewer1.DataBind();
      }
      catch(Exception er)
      {
          throw;
      }
      }
```

Comment: When you host your application in IIS, the application user get changed from current login user to application pool identity. Have you checked with that and its permission to database?

Comment: i tried to connect as corrent login user but still same error

Comment: where should i check the permission for database? the sql user have full permission for db

Comment: Have you tried the solution here?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28119692/crystal-reports-failed-to-open-the-connection